# Getting url and content on EVERY page from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First of all, all the answers will be much appriciated, as I'm running out of my own ideas.

I have a "simple" problem to tackle. I wanna do a chrome extension, which would basically track the websites you're visiting (with content included). **To clarify, we have full consent of the users to do this.** :-)

What I did so far, isn't working well (I've tried to use many of the hooks provided by chrome API, ie `chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted`, `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted`, `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect`, `chrome.history.onVisited`).

The best option so far is to use `chrome.history.onVisited`, but then again, I've no idea how to get website content from it - I've tried to execute content script which returns `document.documentElement.outerHTML`, but in order to do so I need to know `tabId`, which isn't available there.

Basically, something is messed up in chrome API or my thinking - probably the latter :)

I want to point out, that it almost works, but not on all cases. It's hard for me to debug which cases fail though.

**Thanks a lot** for all the tips I can get!

Comment: Are you trying to get historical websites or only the ones being viewed at the moment?

Comment: only ones that are viewed from certain point. ie user clicks button "start tracking" and I want to gather all pages since then untill she/he decides to click "stop" button. so, yeah, much more "viewed at the moment" than historical ones.

Comment: And do you need only content as a HTML or do you separately want list of resources (JS, CSS, images and so on) and an HTML?

Comment: html only is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification in a comment I could suggest you to use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

At the moment when the user press "start recording" button you can - from the background page - [execute content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) which will intersect content of the pages already opened and then will send it back to the background page for further processing (save possibly). You can query for all tabs in any window using [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) function:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
   console.log(tabs); //tabs array contain all tabs in all windows.
});
```

Iterating over this array you can execute script in all tabs using it's tab.id:

```
tabs.forEach(function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { 'file': 'cs.js' })
});
```

Then you can attach event handler to listen up for changes in tabs:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(change){
  if(change.status === 'complete'){
     //inject content script
  }
});
```

Second scenario is to add content script to every page user visits adding proper manifest entry:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["cs.js"]
  }
],
...
```

After cs.js load you can call background page and ask it if the extension should capture page content (using messaging passing). If yes - do the same as above, if not, just do nothing.

It is the easiest and most convenient way of doing what you need.

Comment: Oh, and inside the content script you can use whatever method you want to get content of the page.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer, I'm gonna test that out. One question though, are content scripts executed even if page redirect (I mean JS or META redirection, not 3xx status codes). I did a simple script, with console.log(document.documentElement.outerHTML); and I've got the source, however, it was the source of the "last" page only (the 3-4 redirections were not shown in the console).

Comment: To clarify it was a content script with manifest definition to be exectued on every page, with an option `'run_at': 'document_start'`.

Comment: No, content script will run during page load or after load (depending on execution time setting). But it will not be loaded during any 30x redirect since there's no page to be executed on. You can use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect` event to catch redirection and insert it to the store separately. Since this response will not contain payload you can only store information about the URL and response headers (if necessary). Also you can read target URL from "Location" header.